# A website opens in new tab by itself

Tags: browser, browser-tabs

There has been a certain problem in my laptop whenever I open the browser. Whenever I try to open a link in my browser, as soon as I press right button on my laptop mouse pad, a new browser opens by itself which then proceeds to tell me that there is a certain virus in my computer. Also something about DNS unlocker shows up in the every link items in the browser. I don't know what is going on in my laptop. I would therefore like to ask for help with you guys. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run any malware/virus scanning utilities? Sounds like you've got yourself a bug.

Comment: @jatuttle0 Yeah, I had run the windows defender, but it showed nothing.

Comment: Try running MalwareBytes, AVG, etc.

Comment: @idiosincrasia23- Windows Defender is not designed to remove malware.  Have you ran software, designed to remove adware, if you have not you should.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 1):

I think, there has been installed virus plug-in into your browser. It would probably get you to install worse virus under admin permission into your pc, which will "help" you, but probably spy you. It is probably, they would steal yours passwords and money.

So, what to do with it? Try to download and make `Avast Rescue Disk`. Then let it check yours whole PC.

https://www.avast.com/faq.php?article=AVKB114

If it won't help you, try to reinstall your PC and, the important part, INSTALL GOOD ANTIVIRUS!